# Remove rows that have 7 or less values/characters?

Tags: r

We have values in the "Identifier" column of which the values range from 7-11 characters/numbers. Is there a way to drop rows that have values with more than 9 characters?

> ```
> Identifier    X1  X2  X3  X4
> 2021047.PR    0   0   1   9
> 2021047.YB    3   0   3   0
> 2021047.C     0   5   0   3
> 2020048       8   6   2   0
> 2021049.Arv   7   0   3   0
> 2021049.BR    0   3   0   8
> 2021049.C     3   0   0   1
> 2021050       4   0   7   0
> ```

Desired Result: Dplyr/Tidy results preferred

> ```
> Identifier    X1  X2  X3  X4
> 2021047.C     0   5   0   3
> 2020048       8   6   2   0
> 2021049.C     3   0   0   1
> 2021050       4   0   7   0
> ```

```
structure(list(Identifier = c("2021047.PR", "2021047.YB", "2021047.C", 
"2020048", "2021049.Arv", "2021049.BR", "2021049.C", "2021050"
), X1 = c(0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 7L, 0L, 3L, 4L), X2 = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 
6L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L), X3 = c(1L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 7L), 
    X4 = c(9L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nchar` to obtain the length of string

```
> subset(df, nchar(Identifier) <= 9)
  Identifier X1 X2 X3 X4
3  2021047.C  0  5  0  3
4    2020048  8  6  2  0
7  2021049.C  3  0  0  1
8    2021050  4  0  7  0
```